# Rotating GameObject does not rotate child

Tags: unity, c#

I am rotating a gameobject that has a child game object with a particle effect on it.

It's a missile with engine exhaust.

[image]

I am rotating the parent game object but the particle effect child objects do not rotate:

[image]

The missile object has this script on it:

```
void FixedUpdate () {
Vector3 dir = targetObject.position - transform.position;
dir.Normalize();

float zAngle = Mathf.Atan2( dir.y, dir.x ) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - 90;
Quaternion desiredRotation = Quaternion.Euler( 0, 0, zAngle );

transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards( transform.rotation, desiredRotation, 10.0f * Time.deltaTime );
rigidBody.AddForce( transform.up * 10.0f, ForceMode2D.Force );
}
```

Particle Effect:

[image]
[image]

Anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Yep, we see! Show us the screenshot of your `ParticleSystem` component. If you're using the `VelocityOverLifetime `module, set your `SimulationSpace` of the particleSystem to `Local` instead of `World`.

Comment: @Spectre I have added the screenshot. I am using `Local`

Answer (score 1):

The answer is on the Particle,  under the `Renderer`, Change `Billboard Alignment` to `Local`.  Thanks to @spectre for the idea of using Local.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You are applying the rotation to the `rigidBody` component, which will apply transformation only to the object with the `rigidBody`, which the particle system does not have.

Note that the particle system will still be dragged along with the parent `gameObject` as it is a child of it, but it will not experience the force transformations.
I would suggest to apply a `Transform.Rotate` to the particle system separately in the next line to match the parent rotation.

Read https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Rigidbody.html - Parenting section.

Comment: This is not the correct way. Please see my answer @raghavendra-singh-dasila

Comment: My reasoning is not incorrect however for the explanation of the phenomenon observed. Albeit your method is quicker and easy. @user-44651

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Moving a rigidbody on a parent object will update that parent object's transform, and that modified transform will affect child transforms nested under it in the hierarchy just the same as manipulating Transform.Rotate directly. The documentation you cite talks about the opposite case: when the rigidbody is on a child object, it will experience physics-driven motion partly independently of its parent's transformation.